# How did Cecilia Lisbon end up in Calcutta?

Tags: plot-explanation, virgin-suicides

In Virgin Suicides (1999), Cecilia Lisbon commits suicide at age 13.

But she ends up in Calcutta as Bride:

[image]

Narration in the movie:

> Cecilia hadn't died. She was a bride in Calcutta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the narration.

This is what happened in the boys' **imagination**...not reality.

[**Shmoop.com**](http://www.shmoop.com/the-virgin-suicides/neighborhood-boys-narrators.html)

> As the girls continue to be stuck in the house, the boys continue their detective work. They watch the mailbox and find out what catalogs and travel brochures the girls have ordered and order them themselves:
>
> > "We got them all. And, flipping pages, hiked through dusty passes with the girls, stopping every now and then to help them take off their backpacks, placing our hands on their warm, moist shoulders and gazing off at papaya sunsets. We drank tea with them in a water pavilion, among blazing goldfish. We did whatever we wanted to do, and Cecilia hadn't killed herself: she was a bride in Calcutta, with a red veil and the soles of her feet dyed with henna."